# "TypeError object undefined" happening when using useContext

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I am testing `useContext`, but I'm getting a error that I am not understanding how to fix it, the idea of the application is to make a counter using `useContext`, each time the button is hitted the counter increases by one.

I created a counter component:

```js
import { useContext } from "react";

import { CountContext } from "../../context/Count";

export const Counter = () => {
  const { count, setCount } = useContext(CountContext);

  return (
    <h2>Counter: {count}</h2>

    // <button
    //   onClick={() => {
    //     setCount(count + 1);
    //   }}
    // >
    //   Count + 1
    // </button>
  );
};
```

This is calling the following context:

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const CountContext = createContext();

export default function CountProvider({ children }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <CountContext.Provider value={{ count, setCount }}>
      {children}
    </CountContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I am getting  the following error:
[image]

I do not have any idea on what is causing the error, I've made a codesandbox to display the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-error-mwgwt?file=/src/components/counter/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't wrapped your `Counter` component inside `CountProvider`.

Your `App.js` should look like this:

```
import { Counter } from "./components/counter";
import CountProvider from "./context/Count";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CountProvider>
      <Counter />
    </CountProvider>
  );
}
```